# .NET 6 and DataProtection/Encryption

Tags: c#, encryption, razor-pages, .net-6.0

Using a razor pages app and .NET 6, how does this look for encrypting/decrypting data?  I did a bit of research and apparently AES-CBC encryption isn't recommended, and this was the alternative I found (AES_256_GCM).  Also, is there a clean way to turn this into a library that can be reused in other versions of .NET (large environment, it'll take time to upgrade everything)?

It's close to other posts about using it in .NET core, but some minor (yet "it won't work without it") tweaks:

Program.cs file:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AuthenticatedEncryption;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AuthenticatedEncryption.ConfigurationModel;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddDataProtection();
builder.Services.AddDataProtection()
       .UseCryptographicAlgorithms(new AuthenticatedEncryptorConfiguration()
       {
           EncryptionAlgorithm = EncryptionAlgorithm.AES_256_GCM,
           ValidationAlgorithm = ValidationAlgorithm.HMACSHA256
       });
builder.Services.AddSingleton<CipherService>();
var app = builder.Build();
```

Class for the cipher:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection;

namespace Encryption.BusinessLogic
{
    public class CipherService 
    {
        private readonly IDataProtectionProvider _dataProtectionProvider;
        private const string Key = "my-very-long-key-of-no-exact-size";
        
        public CipherService(IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider)
        {
            _dataProtectionProvider = dataProtectionProvider;
        }
        public string Encrypt(string input)
        {
            var protector = _dataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector(Key);
            return protector.Protect(input);
        }
        public string Decrypt(string cipherText)
        {
            var protector = _dataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector(Key);
            return protector.Unprotect(cipherText);
        }
    }
}
```

Code behind on the index page:

```
 private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
        private readonly IDataProtectionProvider _dataProtectionProvider;
        [BindProperty]
        public string InputText { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public string Enc { get; set; }
        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger, IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _dataProtectionProvider = dataProtectionProvider;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {

        }
        public void OnPost()
        {
            CipherService cipher = new CipherService(_dataProtectionProvider);
            Enc = cipher.Encrypt(InputText);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've taken a different approach by using this article, https://code-maze.com/data-protection-aspnet-core/. I've made a minor change. On the controller: I've added the following declaration to deal with Route Constraints. So far it's working for me. This is for .Net Core.

```
[Route("Controller/Action/{id:regex(^[[a-zA-Z0-9_-]]*$)}")] // matches alpha, number, plus _ and + 
public async Task<IActionResult> EditPermission(string id)
{
`var decryptedId = Convert.ToInt32(_dataProtector.Unprotect(id));
}
```